# Meio Upload Strict Errors

Tags: cakephp, meio-upload

```
Strict (2048): Declaration of MeioUploadBehavior::setup() should be compatible with ModelBehavior::setup(Model $model, $config = Array) [APP/Plugin/MeioUpload/Model/Behavior/MeioUploadBehavior.php, line 26]

Strict (2048): Declaration of MeioUploadBehavior::beforeValidate() should be compatible with ModelBehavior::beforeValidate(Model $model) [APP/Plugin/MeioUpload/Model/Behavior/MeioUploadBehavior.php, line 26]

Strict (2048): Declaration of MeioUploadBehavior::beforeSave() should be compatible with ModelBehavior::beforeSave(Model $model) [APP/Plugin/MeioUpload/Model/Behavior/MeioUploadBehavior.php, line 26]

Strict (2048): Declaration of MeioUploadBehavior::afterSave() should be compatible with ModelBehavior::afterSave(Model $model, $created) [APP/Plugin/MeioUpload/Model/Behavior/MeioUploadBehavior.php, line 26]

Strict (2048): Declaration of MeioUploadBehavior::beforeDelete() should be compatible with ModelBehavior::beforeDelete(Model $model, $cascade = true) [APP/Plugin/MeioUpload/Model/Behavior/MeioUploadBehavior.php, line 26]

Strict (2048): Declaration of MeioUploadBehavior::afterDelete() should be compatible with ModelBehavior::afterDelete(Model $model) [APP/Plugin/MeioUpload/Model/Behavior/MeioUploadBehavior.php, line 26]
```

Comment: Do you have any code you could share with us to help us debug?

Answer (score 5):

The method signatures of the `MeioUploadBehavior` must be the same as those of the `ModelBehavior` class.

For example, the method signature of the `afterDelete` method must be changed from `function afterDelete(&$model)` to `function afterDelete(Model $model)`.

Answer (score 4):

Change the file MeioUploadBehavior

```
function beforeValidate(Model $model)
function beforeSave(Model $model)
function afterSave(Model $model, $created)
```

by:

```
function beforeValidate(Model $model, $options = array())
function beforeSave(Model $model, $options = array())
function afterSave(Model $model, $created, $options = array())
```

This correction is due to changes made ​​by CakePHP Version.

Greeting

@jvo_chile